# Isekai manga where the main character is taught magic by an old elf

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I remember this was an isekai manga but the main character is not reincarnated nor does he remember his past life. He was raised and taught magic and stuff like this by an old elf (the old elf says to him he is weak but in fact he is OP).

He leaves his home and goes on an adventure but soon he meets a noble lady being chased by some goblin chimeras. He saves her and she takes him to her home and after some dialog she says to him to become a magic teacher at her school and after a while he agrees.

The old elf was very powerful and the main character becomes even more powerful. He told him he was weak to not make him arrogant before he left to become an adventurer. I don't remember how he saves the lady (it was magic or a spirt/summon). She wants him to become a teacher because of his strength (to not waste his power/life?) and I classified it as isekai because it is like a isekai world (adventurers, goblins, guilds, magic, etc)

I remember he summoned something and in his chant it referred to Lucifer, but the spirit/demon was a small lady and did not had the name Lucifer.

Comment: You say you read this a while ago, can you remember how long ago? Why did the old elf say he was weak when he wasn't? Why did he leave? How does he save the lady? Why does she want him to become a teacher? Can you remember anything after that? Why are you classifying this as isekai? If you remember anything else please [edit] your question to include those details.

Comment: *Isekai* is a genre about being transported to another world, whether it's by magic, portals, reincarnation, or the like. Was that how he got there?

Comment: from what i remember no

Comment: I'm not understanding something. If he wasn't reincarnated and doesn't remember his past life, how in hell does he end up being raised? Was he summoned as a baby and raised to adulthood? And isekai has to be either reincarnated, summoned, transported themselves, or accidentally were transported, like the one where a hole opened up and people fell into another world. The only way he wouldn't remember his old life is if he was too young when it happened or his memory was wiped.

Answer (score 2):

This is *[Assistant Teacher in the Magical Girls' School](https://myanimelist.net/manga/131345)*

> Lou Brandel, a genius wizard with a talent for thousands of years. One day helped a beautiful aristocratic daughter, Franc and was to be assigned to "Magic Girls' Gakuen" where he acts as a teacher! Now, the "non-standard" teacher life by the strongest wizard opens!

According to the tags, it is not an transmigration or reincarnation story at all. It does take place in another world, but with no relation to our own. It's isekai by a literal definition, but not in how the term is usually used in English.

The description is a solid match for the events of the first chapter. A noblewoman is attacked by some goblin-like chimeras...

[image: Goblin chimeras]

and easily dispatches them by summoning a spirit named Salamander. Afterwards, he tells the girl he was trained by a 7000 year old elf ("Arlv"). He tells her he wants to become an adventurer, and she insists she becomes a teacher instead, despite his teacher telling him he's still a newbie.

[image: Noble insists he work as a teacher]

Answer (score 1):

[Mofumofu to Isekai Slow Life o Mezashimasu](https://mangaclash.com/manga/mofumofu-to-isekai-slow-life-o-mezashimasu/)

It is this one right? I have been looking for this as well.

> The place where the overworked adolescent man was dropped was a different world.
> Having been turned into a boy Arito, while playing with monsters, he is led by the old elven man Oost and becomes familiar with the life of the magical forest.